# LNK2001 error on atoi and stoi function with proper includes added

Tags: c++, configuration, linker, include, lnk2001

I have this project that throws `LNK2001` error on using `atoi` while proper includes added:

```
#... //other headers
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

BOOL main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    ShowNumber(atoi(argv[1]));
    return TRUE;
}
```

Error is: `LNK2001: Unresolved external symbol _atoi`

I do know that LNK error happens while a header confusion occurs. But i don't think that headers are the problem here. Is there anything in the project configuration or header conflict that may cause this to break? Also i get 15 other LNK2001 on using `std::stoi`.

Visual studio 2017 with 2015 or 2017 toolset.

Comment: `BOOL` being just a typedef for `int`, why not use actual `int` as is standard?

Comment: @DavisHerring You are right. But i thought it might be cleaner this way. I don't think it affect performance.

Comment: I would call it less clean (and needlessly Windows-specific), but it certainly doesn’t affect performance.